# How to know whether wget has completed download successfully?

Tags: linux, wget

I attempted to download openSUSE 12.1 through wget.
*It stopped after 64% showing:*

```
05:54:48 (120.30 KB/s) - `openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso' saved 4429185024/4429185024]
```

**It appears that the download is complete but then why does it show 64% only?**

```
anisha@linux-2gbt:~> wget -c http://ftp.uni-bremen.de/pub/mirrors/opensuse/distribution/openSUSE-stable/iso/openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso
--11:39:58--  http://ftp.uni-bremen.de/pub/mirrors/opensuse/distribution/openSUSE-stable/iso/openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso
           => `openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso'
Resolving ftp.uni-bremen.de... 134.102.228.70
Connecting to ftp.uni-bremen.de|134.102.228.70|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4,429,185,024 (4.1G) [application/x-iso9660-image]

47% [===========================================>                                                  ] 2,425,434,388   --.--K/s  ETA 8:59:38

19:55:21 (79.70 KB/s) - Read error at byte 2425434388/4429185024 (Connection timed out). Retrying.

--19:55:22--  http://ftp.uni-bremen.de/pub/mirrors/opensuse/distribution/openSUSE-stable/iso/openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso
  (try: 2) => `openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso'
Connecting to ftp.uni-bremen.de|134.102.228.70|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4,429,185,024 (4.1G) [application/x-iso9660-image]

64% [===========================================================>                                  ] 4,429,185,024  192.61K/s  ETA 5:28:09

05:54:48 (120.30 KB/s) - `openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso' saved [4429185024/4429185024]
```

**I attempted to start it again thinking since I had used `-c` option, it won't start downloading all over again if once the download is truly complete, but it did start again. What should I conclude from this?**

```
anisha@linux-2gbt:~> wget -c http://ftp.uni-bremen.de/pub/mirrors/opensuse/distribution/openSUSE-stable/iso/openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso
--08:50:56--  http://ftp.uni-bremen.de/pub/mirrors/opensuse/distribution/openSUSE-stable/iso/openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso
           => `openSUSE-12.1-DVD-i586.iso'
Resolving ftp.uni-bremen.de... 134.102.228.70
Connecting to ftp.uni-bremen.de|134.102.228.70|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4,429,185,024 (4.1G) [application/x-iso9660-image]

 2% [=>                                                                                              ] 207,066,532   93.31K/s ETA 15:56:35^C
anisha@linux-2gbt:~>
```

Comment: Have you checked the md5sum of downloaded file with md5sum given at site ?

Comment: Don't use wget, use bittorrent. I see that http://software.opensuse.org/121/en has a torrent option. I tried it, and I'm getting a reasonably fast download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did `$?` say? Usually, checking the return value helps.

Also, try to verify md5sum of downloaded file against the one on the internet to make sure, it's OK.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how to use "$?". :redface: and, ofcourse verifying midsum would help. but I wish to know how to verify the output of wget on its own.

Comment: @AnishaKaul `$?` is the return value of the last executed command in the shell. It is supposed to be `0` if the command executed correctly otherwise it is non-zero. E.g you can do `[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "No error"`

Comment: @UlrichDangel that's a very nice information. thansk. I'll try and see.

Comment: I re ran the command and this time it automatically stopped at 99%. I ran `$?`. It returned 0 - now I can assume that the download is successful?